# How to split text lines into proper fields

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do in my system is to copy from email the people footer and paste it to txtarea,
and then automatically split it to proper fields:

- name
- lastname
- email
- telephone

The thing is, how to automatically check which line is which position (name, phone etc.)?
I think:

- if we have a "@" in the line we know that this is email address
- if we have a digitis we know that this is a telephone (so we need to copy only numbers and + before number if occur)
- another line with two words should be: first word name and second word surname
- and any other lines should be ignored

HTML:

```
<form>

  <textarea name="footer" id="footer" rows="10" cols="30">
  John James
  tel. +44 (12) 345678
  john.james@gmail.com
  this two lines
  should be ignored
  </textarea><input type='button' id='click' value='convert'>
  <br>
  First name:<br>
  <input type='text' id='firstname'><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="lastname"><br>
  Telephone:<br>
  <input type="text" id="telephone"><br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" id="email">

</form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('click').onclick = (function() { 
    alert('Just a test if button works');
});
```

Here is my jsfiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/89jqpxrq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data format is not going to change then here is what you can do:

This is your HTML (I changed it a little bit):

```
<form>

  <textarea name="footer" id="footer" rows="10" cols="30">
  John James
  tel. +44 (12) 345678
  john.james@gmail.com
  this two lines
  should be ignored
  </textarea>
  <button id="convert" type="button" form="form" value="Convert">Convert</button>
  <br>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br>
  Telephone:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"><br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">

</form>
```

And here is Javascript part:

```
const doc = document;
doc.get = doc.getElementById;
function convert(event) {
    const text = doc.get('footer').value;
    const [name, telephone, mail] = text.split('\n').map(x => x.trim());
    const [first, last] = name.split(' ');

    doc.get('firstname').value = first.replace(/\s/g, '');
    doc.get('lastname').value = last.replace(/\s/g, '');
    doc.get('telephone').value = telephone.replace(/\s|[^0-9\+\(\)]/g, '');
    doc.get('email').value = mail.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
doc.get('convert').addEventListener('click', convert);
```

It follows the new ES6 syntax, if that's a problem then here is the 'standard' Javascript:

```
var doc = document;
doc.get = doc.getElementById;
function convert(event) {
    var text = doc.get('footer').value,
        array = text.split('\n').map(function(item){
            return item.trim();
        }),
        name = array[0],
        telephone = array[1],
        mail = array[2];
    array = name.split(' ');
    var first = array[0],
        last = array[1];

    doc.get('firstname').value = first.replace(/\s/g, '');
    doc.get('lastname').value = last.replace(/\s/g, '');
    doc.get('telephone').value = telephone.replace(/\s|[^0-9\+\(\)]/g, '');
    doc.get('email').value = mail.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
doc.get('convert').addEventListener('click', convert);
```

If you make a few assumptions:
- name is always Word Word Word... (uppercase followed by lowercases)
- telephone contains only + ( ) 0-9 (it doesn't check if parentheses are matched, you can just believe the customer that the number is correct and assume he missed one parenthese, when you perform calls you don't click () anyways.

```
const doc = document;
doc.get = doc.getElementById;

function convert(event) {
    const text = doc.get('footer').value;
    const info = {};
    const regexpName = /^([A-Z][a-z]+){2,}$/g;
    const regexpPhone = /[+()0-9]/g;
    const regexpMail = /(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    let clean;
    text.split(/\n/).map(item => {
        item = item.trim();
        clean = item.replace(/\s/g, '');
        if(regexpName.test(clean)) {
            if(!info.name) {
                info.name = item.split(' ');
            }
        } else if(regexpPhone.test(clean)) {
            info.telephone = item.replace(/[^+()0-9]/g, '');
        } else if(regexpMail.test(item)) {
            info.mail = item.match(regexpMail)[0];
        }
    });
    info.last = info.name.pop();
    info.first = info.name.join(' ');


    doc.get('firstname').value = info.first;
    doc.get('lastname').value = info.last;
    doc.get('telephone').value = info.telephone;
    doc.get('email').value = info.mail;
}
doc.get('convert').addEventListener('click', convert);
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you for your time and contribution. This is very good. But I never know where will be a specific line. I need to copy user footer. And the footers can be different in every email. For example the email address can be in first, second or third line. So I need also to add a solution to guess what is the data type. (if we have only to words I would say it will be name and surname, if "@" this shoul be an email etc).
I will appreciate any additional help.

Comment: Well, the lines with phone number and email you can detect looking for numbers and some mail pattern correspondingly. But if you're looking for name and surname, there can be 2 words or more (in some countries you have names like Ludvig van Beethoven), so that's 2+ words. How about the other lines that you should ignore? What content will there be? Is it going to be a string of letters without spaces? And are the phone, names and mail going to be always in the first 3 lines? If yes then you can detect them easily. Can you provide more information? Are all 5 lines always randomly mixed?

Comment: I added new code at the end of my post, check if that satisfies your needs.

Comment: Hello Azamantes: your old code works fine. But the new won't start. Could you please take a look. I've added it to new jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hhnnxdu9/1/

BTW: In footers most of the times it is email, phone number, name/surname and many time job title (which we can ignore). Name / surname is always in the firsts line, never before job title. Mail and number are quite easy to decode.

Comment: I updated the last piece of code. The example is at https://jsfiddle.net/hhnnxdu9/5/. I've put some gibberish at the beginning of line in email and before and after telephone number and it seems to work. By `it doesn't start` you mean it doesn't work properly or it doesn't even do anything?

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution is really helpful for me. I had a trouble starting your code but after small investigation I've found that the problem is only on Safari web browser on my Mac. On Firefox and Chrome everything it's working fine. Thank you once again :-)

Comment: actually my question is already answered .. but to be honest I will be helpfull for one more addition. To cover "job title". We can say that if in one line is "Name Surname" and in second we have something different then phone/email it should be the job title. Additionally to make sure this is a job title we can try to find if in this line we have word from array [IT, manager, CEO] etc. Of course I know I need to build large arrays of words, but this is only option. Normally I would say if we have two lines in first is Name Surname, in second job
https://jsfiddle.net/hhnnxdu9/7/

Comment: I am trying to do it myself but I am having a trouble with regular expressions:
https://jsfiddle.net/hhnnxdu9/8/
Also I found that I can use filter like `^.*\b(IT|manager|CEO|administrator)\b.*$` but it won't work with your code for me.

Comment: Hello @azamantes once again - (a właściwie cześć). It works now with two small issue.
**First:** It is not working with polish letters in names (np. Paweł Kąkol).
What do you think to change regexpName from: `/^([A-Z][a-z]+){2,}$/g`  to: `/^([\sa-zA-ZĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż]+){2,}$/g`  ?
**Second:** If we do not have email or job title in original text instead of having empty field we have word "undefined"

Comment: Cześć. Well the second issue can be easily resolved by doing `doc.get('job_title').value = info.job_title || '';`. The first problem comes from lack of Unicode support in Javascript's RegExp. So yes, you can do it like that, or instead of 'ąęóĄĘÓ' etc you can put corresponding unicode values, like `\u00E0` or something (which I find more obscure, especially if you want to change the regexp in the future). If you decide to use the 'ąęó' etc though, bare in mind that you need to use correct file encoding on your computer.

Comment: still having problem. When I've added polish letters something went wrong. But even without won;t work with similar data:
https://jsfiddle.net/hhnnxdu9/14/
Your help is big, if you can leave me your address I can send you a small gift for your help

PS. also is it away to have an array not case sensitive

Comment: It really depends on how formatted the data is going to be. I think information about job position should be written like `Senior IT Manager` indeed, not `senior it manager` so in this case I think it's better to keep it case sensitive.

Comment: After few days of tests works fine in 90% of tests :-) Thank you once again for help.
What can be better? 1. If the name ans surname end with "," script can't find the name/surname. 2. Sometimes if is more then one number system is using the last one, wchich can be wrong. For example in footer many times we can find information about VAT number or any other numbers

Comment: I'll look at it in a few hours when I have time, make a jsfiddle for me to have something to test, it would be helpful. Put some examples that don't work in there.

Answer (score 0):

This can get pretty complicated as there are a lot of possible permutations (Like when someone puts their phone and email on the same line), but this might get you started:

Get an array of the lines in the textarea into a variable:

```
var f = document.getElementById('footer').value.split("\n");
```

Loop through each line in your array and do some checks to see if the line meets some criteria. If it does, populate the applicable fields:

```
for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    if (f[i].indexOf('@') > -1) {
        // This is probably an email address
        document.getElementById("email").value = f[i];
    } else if (f[i].indexOf('0') > -1) {
        // This may be a phone number
        // Do something else here
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, that is interesting. Thank you. I thought about similar idea. How to find if there a line have only two words (possible name lastname)?

Comment: @Tikky, one way you can check if a line contains 2 words is as follows: `(line.trim().length - line.trim().replace(' ','').length) === 1`

Answer (score 0):

if you enter data as same as your example that means enter all thing in new line then try

HTML

```
<form>

<textarea name="footer" id="footer" rows="10" cols="30">
John James
tel. +44 (12) 345678
john.james@gmail.com
this two lines
should be ignored
</textarea>
<button id="convert" type="button" form="form" value="Convert"/>Convert</button>
  <br>
  </form> 
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"><br>
  Telephone:<br>
  <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone"><br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
```

JavaScript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function (){
   $("#convert").click(function(){
    //  alert('abc');
      var str= document.getElementById('footer').value;
    //alert(str);
      var dtail = str.split('\n');
    //alert(dtail[0]);
      var fnmAndLnm = dtail[0].split(" ");

      $('#firstname').val(fnmAndLnm[1]);
      $('#lastname').val(fnmAndLnm[2]);
      $('#telephone').val(dtail[1]);
      $('#email').val(dtail[2]);
     }); 
});  
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is I never know in which line is which information. Every user email footer is different, so I am trying to find best solution which can extract the information from any (or most of) footers.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use the JS function: split

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
```

The result of res will be an array with the values:

```
How,are,you,doing,today?
```

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.

Here`s a reference for how to use:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: I know how split works, but the thing is how to find in which line is which data format.